# Web API error logging

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API project and I have added a custom exception filter.  In this exception filter, I would like to log the JSON data the client posted to the server.  I don't seem to have access to it though.  Can someone help me with where in the objects I can gain access to it?

actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.Request.Content seems to be empty, but in my simulated scenarios I know valid data was posted.

```
public class MobileAppExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async void OnException( HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext )
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append( $"Url:{actionExecutedContext.Request.RequestUri}" );

        foreach(var header in actionExecutedContext.Request.Headers)
        {
            sb.Append( $"Header:{header.Key} - {String.Join( ", ", header.Value )}" );
        }...
   }
}
```

Comment: Check the request `Request.Method` for POST and then check the `Request.Content`

Comment: When you say `seems to be empty.`  What does that mean?  The property is `null`?

Comment: Well when I do a "quick watch" although is says it has: 
{Content-Length: 3156
Content-Type: application/json
}
this is it's actual contents:
  actionExecutedContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() Id = 382, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "" System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>

Comment: `actionExecutedContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` without an `await` till return a `Task` which is what you are describing in your last comment. the await will convert the content to a readable string. If you are not going to use the `await` then use `actionExecutedContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`

Comment: I tried with both result and await and they both return the empty string.  the result listed is what comes from the quick watch which shows how it is somehow empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try like this to see if you can get the json :

```
   string RequestContent = "";

  RequestContent = Extract_Json_From_Request(actionContext.Request.Content);

  private string Extract_Json_From_Request(HttpContent Requestcontent) 
        {
            string RequestBody = "";

            try
            {
                var content = Requestcontent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                RequestBody = content.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RequestBody = ex.Message;

            }
            return RequestBody;

        }
```

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm, how is that different to all the other methods that seemed to come with empty content?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that there is actually content there to be read before trying to access it.

```
public class MobileAppExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async void OnException( HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext )
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var request = actionExecutedContext.Request;
        sb.Append( $"Url:{request.RequestUri}" );

        foreach(var header in request.Headers)
        {
            sb.Append( $"Header:{header.Key} - {String.Join( ", ", header.Value )}" );
        }

        if(request.Method == HttpMethod.Post && request.Headers.ContentLength > 0) {
            var content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            sb.Append( $"Content:{content}"); 
        } 
   }
}
```